# The data types varchar and varchar are incompatible in the modulo operator SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I get this error:

> The data types varchar and varchar are incompatible in the modulo operator.

when running this code

```
' Number LIKE '%' + @search + '%' ';
```

The number is an integer and this code snippet appears enclosed in ''; due to a dynamic pivot statement. Any ideas how  i can run this? thanks

Comment: Please show a more complete SQL statement.

Comment: If your percent sign, meant to be around your search parameter, i.e. `WHERE Foo LIKE '%bar%'` and you get a modulo operator error, you have a quote mismatch somewhere. Read [ask] and show a [mcve].

Comment: Could you use an IDE that color codes string literals so that you could see the problem yourself?

Answer (score 3):

Presumably, you have something like this:

```
SELECT ' Number LIKE '%' + @search + '%' ';
```

If so, you have single quotes inside a string.  So the "string" is interpreted as:

```
SELECT (' Number LIKE ') % (' + @search + ') % (' ');
```

The `%` is the modulo operator . . . and hence your error.

In order to put single quotes in a string, you need to double them up.  Something like this:

```
SELECT ' Number LIKE ''%'' + @search + ''%'' ';
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need those outer quotes, should it not just be

```
Number LIKE '%' + @search + '%'
```

Otherwise you'll need to escape the inner quotes. Try this:

```
'Number LIKE ''%'' + @search + ''%'''
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `%` is a [modulo operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/modulo-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) in SQl Server and it is interpreted as such because to insert quto in a string you need to **double it** as other answers suggest.

Other solution would be:

```
'CHARINDEX(' + @search + ', Number) > 0'
```

I always tend to use that over `LIKE` oprator with `%someString%`. Both determine if there is string within the other.